# angularjs-ui-tinymce binding not works

Tags: angularjs, tinymce, angular-ui-tinymce

I use ui-tinymce to show the auto-generated report.

```
<form method="post">
  <textarea ui-tinymce="tinymceOptions" ng-model="tinyMceContent">
  </textarea>
</form>
```

The content markup is inside the tinyMceContent variable (cause I don't know the oher way to do it), here is the part of it for example:

```
this.$scope.tinyMceContent =  `
    <h1>
        {{test.type}} TEST RESULTS
    </h1> `
```

And it renders like `{{test.type}} TEST RESULTS`, binding doesn't work. As I understand the ui-tinymce was made exactly for solving this kind of problems with angular. The documentation also says that is you have errors you have to rerender page using `this.$scope.$broadcast('$tinymce:refresh');` And I do that in `$onInit`, but it doesn't help either.

So could anyone please explain me how to make the bindings work and is it even possible?

Comment: Which version of Angular are you using?

Comment: @Izio angular 1.6